# Algorithm to find min area covered X percents of geopoints

Tags: algorithm, geolocation

There is a convex geo polygon consisting of 200 vertexes (lat, lng). Lets call it M.
There is a set of geo points inside it (about 15 000 points). P = {1 ... 15 000}.
Also there is another convex geo polygon inside the first one (M) and consisting of 50 vertexes. Lets call it S.
Polygon S contains 43 percent of points of P.
I need some algorithm to increase the area of S (by moving the points of original polygon S) to get minimum area that will contain 55 percent of points of P. Is it possible?

Comment: Of cause that is possible (at least if the new S does not need to be still totally within M). The question is with which algorithm complexity?

Comment: Algorithm complexity does not matter, because it will calculate only once and next I will take just static data. But what it does matter is type of result S' polygon, it has to be convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always possible if the modified S (lets call it S') needs to be 100% within M.

Here the example:

Let M be kind of a circle where 43% of the points are near the center and all 57% other points on the rim of the circle. Let S be a triangle with the corners on the rim of the circle.

There is no way to get more of the points on the rim of the circle within the triangle with just moving the corners of the triangle within M because only maximal 3 of the points on the rim of the circle can be part of the triangle. So you cannot achieve the 55% in S' as long as it has to remain a triangle and the corners need to be inside M.

Comment: No, S' doesn't need to be 100% within M. In that case I will just apply intersection of polygons.

Comment: But what is really important is S' polygon should be the minimal by area because points are unevenly distributed.

Comment: What about adding edges to S? Does S' really need to have the same amount of corners as S?

Comment: It also doesn't matter. We can add or remove edges.

Comment: Remark: The solution polygon will have points from P as edges. But trying all combination is infeasible.

Comment: So, I decided to do next. I enumerate through the points which contains within M but not within S and for each of them I calculate distance to every point which contains within S. I find min distance for every pass and add that point to S like vertex. Slow but correctly I guess.